# On flexibility/power of metapost to create graphs

Tags: metapost

I have the following pgfplots graph embedded in a TeX document that I am happy with. Recently, reading up on metapost, I'd like to try to recreate the graph with it.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width            = \textwidth,
        height           = 1.1\textwidth,
        xlabel           = Days,
        ylabel           = kg,
        xmin             = 0,
        xmax             = 450,
        ymin             = 2,
        grid             = both,
        minor x tick num = 1,
        minor y tick num = 3,
      ]
      \addplot[red, mark=*] table [x=Days, y expr=\thisrow{Weight}/1000] {weight.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P01] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P1] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P3] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P5] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P10] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P15] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
      \addplot[gray, restrict x to domain=0:450] table [x=Age, y=P25] {wfa_boys_p_exp.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

It uses two data files. One is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1c0723182058ba4d14a9) and the other is [here](http://www.who.int/childgrowth/standards/wfa_boys_p_exp.txt).

I use a bunch of features in this graph and wonder whether metapost supports these. For example, restricting x values to a domain, using an expression of a value, x/y min/max, etc.

Is it possible to re-create a graph like this, using the same data files, in metapost?

Comment: Yes, but perhaps in a slightly different way.   Given enough time and patience and skill you can program *anything* in MP, but its strengths are in drawing mathematical pictures rather than reading and processing text files.  Having said that you can do quite a lot with the [MPGraph](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpgraph.pdf) package.  Personally I prefer to take a two-language approach:  I use python (or perl, or awk, or even rexx) to process the data and write the metapost input to draw the pictures.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graph produced from the OP data files using Python to read the files and produce the input for Metapost.

[image]

Here is the Python source. I've used Python3 syntax. To use it:

- save the Python source with a suitable name, perhaps `growth_chart.py`
- save the OP data files in the same place as `weight.txt` and `wfa_boys_p_exp.txt`
- run `python3 growth_chart.py > temp.mp && mpost temp` on your command line
- if this runs without errors, Metapost will have produced `temp1.eps` which you can include in LaTex, or open with a PostScript viewer, or translate to PDF using `convert`, or `ps2pdf`, or OSX Preview, etc...

I've not tried to make it completely general, for example the 450 days and the y-scaling of 40 points per kg are just hard coded.  If you try to make it too general you can end up re-writing the whole of pgfplots.

```py
weight_path = list()

with open('weight.txt', 'rt') as w:
    for line in w:
        date, days, weight, change = line.split()
        if date == 'Date':
            continue
        weight_path.append( (int(days), int(weight)/1000) )

P01_path = list()
P1_path  = list()
P3_path  = list()
P5_path  = list()
P10_path = list()
P15_path = list()
P25_path = list()

with open('wfa_boys_p_exp.txt', 'rt') as p:
    for line in p:
        Age, L, M, S, P01, P1, P3, P5, P10, P15, P25, P50, P75, P85, P90, P95, P97, P99, P999 = line.split()
        if Age == 'Age':
            continue
        if Age == '450':
            break
        P01_path.append( (int(Age), float(P01)) )
        P1_path.append(  (int(Age), float(P1)) )
        P3_path.append(  (int(Age), float(P3)) )
        P5_path.append(  (int(Age), float(P5)) )
        P10_path.append( (int(Age), float(P10)) )
        P15_path.append( (int(Age), float(P15)) )
        P25_path.append( (int(Age), float(P25)) )

print('''
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
defaultfont := "phvr8r";
beginfig(1);
''')

print('path w, p[];')
print('w   = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in weight_path)))
print('p0  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P01_path)))
print('p1  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P1_path)))
print('p2  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P3_path)))
print('p3  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P5_path)))
print('p4  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P10_path)))
print('p5  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P15_path)))
print('p6  = ({}) yscaled 40;'.format('--'.join(str(x) for x in P25_path)))

print('''
path xx, yy;
xx = origin -- (456, 0);
yy = origin -- (0, 406);
for x = 30 step 30 until 450: 
  draw yy shifted (x,0) withcolor .9 white; 
  label.bot(decimal x, (x,0));
endfor
for y = 1 upto 10:
  draw xx shifted (0,40y) withcolor .9 white;
  label.lft(decimal y, (0,40y));
endfor
drawarrow xx; label.rt("Days", point infinity of xx);
drawarrow yy; label.top("Weight (kg)", point infinity of yy);
''')

print('''
draw p0 withcolor .40[blue,white]; label.rt("0.1%" infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p0);
draw p1 withcolor .45[blue,white]; label.rt("1%"  infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p1);
draw p2 withcolor .50[blue,white]; label.rt("3%"  infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p2);
draw p3 withcolor .55[blue,white]; label.rt("5%"  infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p3);
draw p4 withcolor .60[blue,white]; label.rt("10%" infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p4);
draw p5 withcolor .65[blue,white]; label.rt("15%" infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p5);
draw p6 withcolor .70[blue,white]; label.rt("25%" infont defaultfont scaled 0.8, point infinity of p6);

draw w withcolor .67 red; 
for i=0 upto length w: 
   unfill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted point i of w;
     fill fullcircle scaled 2 shifted point i of w;
endfor
''')

print('''
endfig;end.
''')
```